# Query Multiple Rows in the same Table for one Variable

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table setup like this:

> session_id | event_id | moderator | speaker_1 | speaker_2 | speaker_3 | ...keeps going to speaker_10

What I am trying to do is setup a query that searches for 1 variable `"speakerid = 13245"` and check rows

> 'moderator', 'speaker_1', 'speaker_2', 'speaker_3', 'speaker_4', 'speaker_5', 'speaker_6', 'speaker_7', 'speaker_8', 'speaker_9', 'speaker_10'

Then return every 'session_id' corresponding to any row that contains speakerid = 12345 in any of the 11 speaker rows.

I know it has something to do with an INNER JOIN but after a lot of searching I can't find anything specific enough.  I've been following stackoverflow for years now and this is my first ever post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really sounds like you need to normalize this table and have a table of sessions/events and a table of speakers related to it through a third sesssions_speaker table.  That way you don't need to change your table schema when you have an event with 12+ speakers.

That being said, you can query like this to get the result you need

```
SELECT session_id
FROM table
WHERE
moderator = ?
OR speaker_1 = ?
OR speaker_2 = ?
...
OR speaker_11 = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use `LIKE` with `OR` to return the rows where any field contains "speakerid = 12345":

```
SELECT Session_Id
FROM YourTable
WHERE Moderator Like '%speakerid = 13245%' 
   OR speaker_1 Like '%speakerid = 13245%' 
   OR ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on database normalization as `speaker_n` columns are a bad sign.  You probably want a `Speakers` table amd a "Session-Speakers" mapping table.  This would certainly make your query easier, but for now you have no choice but to search all columns:

```
SELECT sesion_id FROM t1 WHERE
    moderator = '12345'
    OR speaker_1 = 12345
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `in` in the `where` clause:

```
select session_id
from t
where 13245 in (moderator, speaker_1, speaker_2, speaker_3, speaker_4, 
                speaker_5, speaker_6, speaker_7, speaker_8, speaker_9, 
                speaker_10)
```